# Fastest way to trim first flash?

Tags: php, string, performance, url

***Scenario: if this was facebook or a huge social networking site and you had to do this millions or billions of times a second, what would be the fastest way?***

Here is my url:

```
http://www.example.com/profile?id=1/name=bob
```

If I use the code:

```
$new_url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

that code will display this:

`/profile?id=1/name=bob`

what is the **fastest** way (performance) to remove the first forward slash so it will be like this: `profile?id=1/name=bob`

I was thinking `ltrim`, `trim`, or `substr` or even more? thanks

Comment: This operation will definitely have __NO__ performance impact in your code.

Comment: @u_mulder sorry see my edit

Comment: You can test yourself, use `microtime` and see difference.

Comment: @u_mulder how can i set up the environment?

Comment: @u_mulder also, are there any other ways to remove the first `/` other than `ltrim`, `trim`, or `substr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest is `substr` when tested with `ltrim`, `substr`, and `preg_replace`. Here is the URL I tested it with: `test.php?osd/lskdifo/idlola`

Order from fastest to slowest:

1. `substr` 0.018708944320679
2. `ltrim` 0.021075963973999
3. `preg_replace` 0.049320220947266

Here are the tests:

**`substr`**:

```
<?php

$x = 0;
$start = microtime(true);
while ($x<=100000) {
    substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $x++;
}
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
echo $time_elapsed_secs;

?>
```

---

**`ltrim`**:

```
<?php

$x=0;
$start = microtime(true);
while ($x<=100000) {
    ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    $x++;
}
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
echo ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
echo $time_elapsed_secs;

?>
```

---

**`preg_replace`**:

```
<?php

$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$x=0;
$start = microtime(true);
while ($x<=100000) {
    preg_replace('/^\//', '', $link);
    $x++;
}
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
echo preg_replace('/^\//', '', $link);
echo $time_elapsed_secs;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There won't be performance difference as such, you can use substr to acheive it

```
substr( $string, 1 );
```